# How to log off user immediately after the view in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to log off the user immediately after the `accessdenied` view displayed so the session token is also gets deleted.

Can someone help me to find a way to do this?

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> AccessDenied() 
    {
        bool haspermission = await _signInService.SignInCurrentUserAsync();
        if (haspermission)
        {              
         return Redirect(redirectUrl);            
        }
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult LogOut()
    {
        return SignOut("Cookies", "oidc");
    }
```

cshtml

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<br />
<br />
<br />
<center>
    <h3>Access Denied</h3>
    <h4>You do not have sufficient rights to access.</h4>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

Request the LogOut action after page loaded.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        $.get('/Controller/Action')
    }
</script>
```